# Where can I find Apple Pay button resources?

Tags: ios, applepay

I'm trying to get a PKPaymentButton with a custom height but am unsuccessful in everything I try. Apple's PKPaymentButton comes back with a  height constraint of 30. Attempting to deactivate/remove constraints and add my own height does nothing. At this point, I'd like to try using their button image resources instead.

The current Apple Pay identity guidelines says they are available at https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/ but there is nothing there. Using the web archive time machine, (https://web.archive.org/web/20160507141217/https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/) the download link is clearly visible but results in a 403 Forbidden.

Anyone know what happened to these resources? Or, if Apple wants to force us to use the PKPaymentButton, how can I change the height and have it scale properly?

Comment: From [Apple Pay Identity Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Apple-Pay-Identity-Guidelines.pdf) "For iOS 8.3 and later, Apple Pay payment buttons must be created using only the Apple-provided
API." - you must use `PKPaymentButton`

Comment: Can you show the code you used to try and change the size of the button?  Adding a height constraint worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I deleted the code, but all I did was instantiate a PKPaymentButton, add the height constraint programmatically, then add it as the view controllers subview. I changed the order to add it as a subview first then constrain it in case there were any side effects, but it made no difference. Can you provide the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Cancel that. Solved. I was missing the old `translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoContraints` gotcha.

```
let applePayButton = PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .buy, paymentButtonStyle: .whiteOutline)
applePayButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
applePayButton.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[applePayButton(==300)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["applePayButton": applePayButton]))
applePayButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: applePayButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100))

controller.view.addSubview(applePayButton)
```